# Dynamic PDF / multiple events

Tags: pdf

I'm creating a dynamic pdf for correctional officer with a fixed number of ''events'' that can be filled. I put 6 possible events that can be filled. However, some individuals have more events. Is it possible to add an option that will allow more cases to appear if the professional filed the maximum cases?

Ty,

Comment: You can do that kind of thing with Java Script in PDF forms, but you're probably better off asking this kind of question at http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Do you know what script can be use ?